# Range unspecified. Specify the :in, :within, :maximum, :minimum, or :is option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i added a validation a my model "entrada":

```
class Entrada < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :titulo, presence: true,
            length: { minimun: 5 }

  attr_accessible :entrada, :titulo
end
```

and so i get the following error:

```
Range unspecified. Specify the :in, :within, :maximum, :minimum, or :is option.
```

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: you right, ok. @johnsyweb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you misspelled `minimum`.